# How to add post listing on home page using page editor in WordPress 2021 theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

On my personal blog https://psychicamelia.com/ I want to add blog posts using page editor on home page if this is easier and possible. I've added some blocks but it only shows one (latest) post. How do I show 5 latest posts? Please see Articles section.

Home page is the default 2021 home page which I've modified.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.